# Merge yyyymmdd, hhmmss and sss columns to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Table IFCD structure as follow:

```
tdate       ttime     updatemillisec
20140730    093014    500
...
```

How to merge columns to one column which names tdatetime, as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm format?

My answer:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(tdate, 4)+'-'+substring(tdate, 5, 2)+'-'+RIGHT(tdate, 2)+' '+ 
            LEFT(ttime, 2)+':'+substring(ttime, 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(ttime, 2)+'.'+ 
            CAST(updatemillisec AS varchar) AS DateTime)
```

Comment: As a hint: [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187928.aspx) function, plus some substring() and concatenation.

Comment: When you say "Solution: ...," does that mean that was the solution you came up with? If so, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (tdate VARCHAR(10)
    ,ttime VARCHAR(10)
    ,Updatemillisec VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('20140730','093014','500')

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), LEFT(tdate, 4) + '-' + 
                            SUBSTRING(tdate, 5, 2) + '-' + 
                            RIGHT(tdate, 2) + SPACE(1) + 
                            LEFT(ttime, 2) + ':' + 
                            SUBSTRING(ttime, 2, 2) + ':' + 
                            RIGHT(ttime, 2) + '.' + 
                            Updatemillisec, 109)
FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this. You would have to concatenate ttime and updatemillisec and and get it to this format `hh:mm:ss.MMM`. Once in that format, Concatenate Date with time in the format `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.MMM`

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (tdate VARCHAR(10),
                  ttime VARCHAR(10),
                  updatemillisec VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES('20140730', '093014', '500')

SELECT CAST(
          ( tdate + ' ' 
          + LEFT(ttime, 2) + ':' 
          + SUBSTRING(ttime, 3, 2) + ':' 
          + RIGHT(ttime, 2) + '.' 
          + updatemillisec) AS DATETIME
         ) AS tDateTime
FROM @Table
```